# Simplifying fractions in SageTEX

Tags: fractions, sagetex

I'm new to SageTex. Here's my code:

> ```
> \documentclass[10pt]{article}
> \usepackage{sagetex}
> \begin{document}
>   \begin{sageblock}
>       var('a,b')
>       a = 3
>   \end{sageblock}\\
>  $\sage{(a-6)/(b-1)}$
> \end{document}
> ```

So this is what I get:

[image]

The point is I don't think it's a "pretty" fraction. I expected something like this:
[image]

I wonder if I could get what I expected? Thank you in advance. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: possibly `var('a,b')` doesn't needed and `$\sage{(a-6)/(b-1)}$` should be `$\frac{\sage{a-6}}{b-1}$`

Comment: @koleygr I want it to be simplified, like $\sage{2/4}$ then it gives 1/2 :D If I use $\frac{\sage{a-6}}{b-1}$, that may not be simplified :D

Comment: Sorry, I have no way to test it because I can't run with this library. I just supposed that what I wrote would give what you expect... Did you tried it? If so, then maybe an `\expandafter` could do the job